# Error: Call was rejected by callee. COMStop() - reading excel password protected files - with R - xl.read.file() function

Tags: r, excel

I'm using the function `pblapply (FileNames, ProcessFile)`

my *ProcessFile* object derives from a function that uses
`xl.read.file ()` (from the `excel.link` package)

inside `pblapply`  `xl.read.file ()` reads several excel files that are in a folder (my input is a list of all file paths - *FileNames*), all files are password protected.

after reading these files, the function makes simple modifications and compiles all the data in a feather file for future analysis.

my problem is that the processing is interrupted and the file the time it is being read opens on its own and I have to enter the password manually, sometimes after entering the password the processing continues (the excel file closes on its own) and other times it is interrupted later addition (the excel file stays open - excel asks if I want to edit).

the error is:

**Error: Call was rejected by callee.**

**Called from: COMStop ("Call was rejected by callee.", -2147418111L)**

**Browse [1]>**

I would need processing to be automatic. Without having to interfere in the process. Can someone help me?

the code is:

```
ProcessFile <- function(FileFullPath){
```

> read Database worksheet from files

```
  DataBase <- xl.read.file(filename = FileFullPath,
                           xl.sheet = "Database",                    
                           password = "xxx", 
                           write.res.password="xxx")
```

> simple modifications

```
  RenameCols <- data.frame(original = names(DataBase), 
                           original_unique = make.unique(names(DataBase))) %>% 
    mutate(visits = if_else(original == "NA", "VISITA_", NA_character_),
           visits_nbr = str_split_fixed(original_unique, "\\.", 2)[,2],
           visits_nbr = as.numeric(visits_nbr),
           visits_nbr = if_else(is.na(visits_nbr), 1, visits_nbr + 1),
           renamed = if_else(original == "NA", paste0(visits, visits_nbr), original))


  names(DataBase) <- RenameCols$renamed

  rm(RenameCols)
```

> read References worksheet from files and simple modifications

```
  RefData <- xl.read.file(filename = FileFullPath,
                          xl.sheet = "Ref", 
                          header = FALSE, 
                          password = "xxx", 
                          write.res.password="xxx") %>% 
    t %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    setnames(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
             c("TOOL_VERSION", "COMPUTER_NAME", "USER_NAME", "EXPORT_TIMESTAMP", "ORIGINAL_FILENAME"))
```

> Data prep

```
  DataBase %<>% 
    mutate(TOOL_VERSION = RefData$TOOL_VERSION[1], 
           COMPUTER_NAME = RefData$COMPUTER_NAME[1], 
           USER_NAME = RefData$USER_NAME[1], 
           EXPORT_TIMESTAMP = RefData$EXPORT_TIMESTAMP[1], 
           ORIGINAL_FILENAME = RefData$ORIGINAL_FILENAME[1]) %>% 
    select(TOOL_VERSION, COMPUTER_NAME, USER_NAME, EXPORT_TIMESTAMP, ORIGINAL_FILENAME, everything())

  rm(RefData)
  invisible(gc())

  return(DataBase)
}
```